# Keyboard not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, keyboard

Well, my keyboard doesn't work on ubuntu if I run it on kernel 3.11 at the start-up screen
there are error messages: atkbd serio0 failed to enable keyboard on isa0060/serio0

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix! Launch this app called 'dconf editor'. Open Desktop -> ibus -> and click on General. Now check the box next to 'use-global-engine' and 'use-system-keyboard-layout'. This worked for me!